# bind tables of different length

Tags: r, arrays

Thank you good ppl! This must be simple but I'm banging my head against it for a while. Please help. I have a large data set from which I get all kinds of information via table(). I then want to store that information which is essentially different counts, so I also want to store the rownames that were counted. For a reproducible example consider

````
```
   a<-c("a","b","c","d","a","b") #one count, occurring twice for a and 
                                   b and once for c and d 
   b<-c("a","c") # a completly different property from the dataset 
                    occurring once for a and c

   x<-table(a) 
   y<-table(b) #so now x and y hold the information I seek
````

```
How can I merge/bind/whatever to get from x and y to this form:

       x. y.
    a  2. 1
    b  2. 0
    c  1. 1
    d. 1  0

HOWEVER,  I need to use the solution iteratively, in a loop that takes x and y and gets the requested form above, and then gets more tables added, each hopefully adding a column. One of my many failed attempts, just to show the logic, is:
     `.  member<-function (data=dfm,groupvar='group',analysis=kc15 {
      res<-matrix(NA,ncol=length(analysis$size)+1)
      res[,1]<-table(docvars(data,groupvar))
      for (i in 1:length(analysis$size)) {
         r<-table(docvars(data,groupvar)[analysis$cluster==i])
         res<-cbind(res,r)
       }
      res
       }`

So, to sum, the reproducible example above means to replicate the first column in res and an r, and I'm seeking (I think) a correct solution instead of the cbind, which would allow adding columns of different length but similar names, as in the example above. 
Please help its embarrassing how much time I'm wasting on this
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, you can use `table`, `stack` and full join the two counts.

```
out <- merge(stack(table(a)), stack(table(b)), by = 'ind', all = TRUE)
out
#  ind values.x values.y
#1   a        2        1
#2   b        2       NA
#3   c        1        1
#4   d        1       NA
```

If you want to replace `NA` with 0, you can do :

```
out[is.na(out)] <- 0
```

Comment: Seems like I mis-specified the problem. So I actually want to use this in a function, to generate an object with several columns that are all the result of table(). When I tried your solution within a loop It doesn't work..

Answer (score 2):

One `purrr` and `tidyr` solution could be:

```
map_dfr(lst, ~ stack(table(.)), .id = "ID") %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = "ID", values_from = "values", values_fill = list(values = 0))

  ind       a     b
  <chr> <int> <int>
1 a         2     1
2 b         2     0
3 c         1     1
4 d         1     0
```

lst being:

```
lst <- list(a = a,
            b = b)
```